# Mercurial with Trac on mod_wsgi

Tags: trac, mercurial

I'm trying to set up a Trac environment running on Apache+mod-wsgi+Mercurial. I've set up everything according to the install docs. However, when I open up the URL to my Trac environment I get:

> Warning: Can't synchronize with the repository (Unsupported version control system "hg": Can't find an appropriate component, maybe the corresponding plugin was not enabled? ).

I've installed `mercurial-trac` from ports.  What could be the problem?

**Update 1**
Found I had to enable the plugin via `trac.ini`.  But I'm still getting an error:

> Unsupported version control system "hg": "Couldn't import symbols: RepoError"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought to update this....turns out I was using the wrong version of the trac-mercurial plugin.